# Creating 3 child records for a particular Object using Apex

Tags: apex, visualforce

Creating 3 child records for a particular Object.

Page1:-

```
<apex:page controller="TestPage1class"><apex:commandButton value="Open" action="{!open}"/></apex:page>
```

Class Code:-

```
public with sharing class TestPage1class {
public Application__c application{get;set;}
public Application_Address__c applicationaddress{get;set;}

public TestPage1class()
{                 
    application = new Application__c();
    applicationaddress = new Application_Address__c();
}

public pageReference Open()
{
   this.application.Client__c = '001i000000CayTs' ; 
   insert (this.application);

   applicationaddress.Type__c = 'Address1';
   applicationaddress.Application__c = this.application.Id;
   upsert (applicationaddress);

   applicationaddress.Type__c = 'Address2';
   applicationaddress.Application__c = this.application.Id;
   upsert (applicationaddress);

   applicationaddress.Type__c = 'Address3';
   applicationaddress.Application__c = this.application.Id;
   upsert (applicationaddress);

    pageReference pageRef = new pageReference('/TestPage2');
    pageRef.setRedirect(true);
    pageRef.getParameters().put('id',application.id);

    return pageRef;
}  }
```

Page 2:-

```
<apex:page standardController="Application__c"  extensions="TestPage2class" ><apex:form><apex:pageBlock id="pbContactdetails">
<apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" id="pbAddr1" title="Address1">
    <apex:inputField value="{!applicationaddress1.Contact_Person__c}"/>
    <apex:inputField value="{!applicationaddress1.Contact_Person_Title__c}"/>
    <apex:inputField value="{!applicationaddress1.Address__c}"/>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
<apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" id="pbAddr2" title="pbAddr2">
    <apex:inputField value="{!applicationaddress2.Contact_Person__c}"/>
    <apex:inputField value="{!applicationaddress2.Contact_Person_Title__c}"/>
    <apex:inputField value="{!applicationaddress2.Address__c}"/>
</apex:pageBlockSection> 
<apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" id="pbAddr3" title="pbAddr3">
    <apex:inputField value="{!applicationaddress3.Contact_Person__c}"/>
    <apex:inputField value="{!applicationaddress3.Contact_Person_Title__c}"/>
    <apex:inputField value="{!applicationaddress3.Address__c}"/>
    <apex:inputField value="{!applicationaddress3.Additional_Instructions__c}"/>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock></apex:form> </apex:page>
```

Page 2 class:-

```
public with sharing class TestPage2class{

public string applicationId {get;set;}

public Application__c application{get; set;}
public Application_Address__c applicationaddress1{get;set;}
public Application_Address__c applicationaddress2{get;set;}
public Application_Address__c applicationaddress3{get;set;}

public TestPage2class(ApexPages.StandardController stdCtrl) 
{       
    this.application=(Application__c)stdCtrl.getRecord();

    if(application != null && application.Id != null)
    {        
        this.application = [SELECT Id, Name
                    FROM Application__c
                    WHERE Id = : application.Id];


        this.applicationaddress1 =[SELECT Type__c, Contact_Person__c, Contact_Person_Title__c, Application__c, Address__c, Additional_Instructions__c 
                                    From Application_Address__c
                                    WHERE Application__c = : this.application.id
                                    AND Type__c = 'Address1' LIMIT 1]; 

        this.applicationaddress2 =[SELECT Type__c, Contact_Person__c, Contact_Person_Title__c, Application__c, Address__c, Additional_Instructions__c 
                                    From Application_Address__c
                                    WHERE Application__c = : this.application.id
                                    AND Type__c = 'Address2' LIMIT 1];

        this.applicationaddress3 =[SELECT Type__c, Contact_Person__c, Contact_Person_Title__c, Application__c, Address__c, Additional_Instructions__c 
                                    From Application_Address__c
                                    WHERE Application__c = : this.application.id
                                    AND Type__c = 'Address3' LIMIT 1];  
    }      
}}
```

Issue Faced:

Not able to create 3 child records for a particular object. There is lookup to application on Application Address. No master detail relationship.

The code is only creating 1 child object and not 3

This is impacting the page2 for giving the output and page2 throwing error

Answer (score 1):

It is only creating one child object because you're using the same applicationAddress variable in the upsert statement. Intialize two variable and then upsert those or the best way is to loop thru the number of child records you want to create and then store all those in a list and then upsert the list.

```
applicationaddress.Type__c = 'Address1';
   applicationaddress.Application__c = this.application.Id;
   upsert (applicationaddress);
  Application_Address__c applicationaddress1 = new Application_Address__c();
   applicationaddress1.Type__c = 'Address2';
   applicationaddress1.Application__c = this.application.Id;
   upsert (applicationaddress1);
    Application_Address__c applicationaddress3 = new Application_Address__c();
   applicationaddres3.Type__c = 'Address3';
   applicationaddres3.Application__c = this.application.Id;
   upsert (applicationaddress3);
```

using for you could do something like below. This is just an example which you can build upon.

```
    list<Application_Address__c> applicationList = new list<application_address__c>();
    set<string> addressSet = new set<string>{'Business Address','Correspondance address','Some other address'};
        for(string s: addressSet){

           Application_Address__c applicationAdd = new Application_Address__c();
           applicationAdd.Type__c = s;
           applicationAdd.Application__c = this.application.Id;
           applicationList.add(applicationAdd);
        }
        upsert applicationList;
```

Comment: Hi Thanks... how do i iterate if i have address type as 'Business Address' and 'Corresoponce address'. Its not address1, address2...

Comment: I want to use List

Comment: Also can i retrieve value using List and use them in page2

Comment: updated the post. Yes, you can pass the value from one page to another as a parameter in the URL and then you can retrieve the parameter value in the second class

Comment: Could you please give me an example